# Drupal 7 Create Flood Table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Because of a long series of events, I thought I lost a site completely due to my hosting company losing a server. Anyway, I'm trying to get back into a site sitting on a server with a cpanel I cant get to and a WHM I cant get to. I only have access to the root dir via ftp. I was able to reset my admin password using the method here https://www.drupal.org/node/1556488

I meant to also clear the flood table, but deleted it instead with `db_drop_table('flood');`

So, now I am getting a MYSQL error when I try to login. So, given I only have access to running php scripts to interact with the SQL database, can anyone help me figure out how to rebuild the flood table via the drupal `db_create_table()` method?

Much appreciated! This has been a nightmare.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. I have written code, I'm just looking for guidance with drupal on how to rebuild the flood table using PHP. Not sure why you think that belongs on the serverfault community.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This isnt my first time asking for help on here. Anyone that knows drupal and PHP would have a pretty clear understanding of what I'm asking for.

Comment: You might consider asking drupal questions here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you needed empty flood table why couldn't you install fresh D7 site somewhere else export table from it and import to your site?

Comment: I didn't have access to PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to rebuild my flood table with a php file ran from the drupal install directory with this in it: Just type in the url mysite.com/myphpfile.php to run it.

```
<?php 
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/password.inc';

  $schema = array();
  $schema['flood'] = array(
    'fields' => array(
      'fid' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'length' => 11,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'event' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 64,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
      'identifier' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 128,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
      'timestamp' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'length' => 11,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'expiration' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'length' => 11,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('fid'),
  );

db_create_table('flood', $schema['flood']);

print "Done. Please delete this file immediately!";
drupal_exit();


?>
```